# Tweaking for fullcalendar axis time format and hide event time

Tags: fullcalendar, time-format

I want to apply these two changes in fullcalendar:

1. Axis time format like: 10:00-11:00, 11:00-12:00, 12:00-13:00...so on.
2. Hide event time only display event name

**Check snap**
[image]

Code I have applied for axis format:

```
jQuery('#fullcal').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    timeFormat: 'H:mm{-H:mmtt }',
    axisFormat: 'H:mm - H:mm',

  events: [
    {
      title: "<?php echo "Booked"; ?>",
      start: new Date(<?php echo "$date, $start"; ?>),
      end: new Date(<?php echo "$date, $end"; ?>),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor : "#1FCB4A",
      textColor: "black",
    },
  ],

});
```

Code `axisFormat: 'H:mm - H:mm',` repeating same time.

And in event `11:00 - Test`, I want only display event name **Test**, if I comment `start:` and `end:` this make disappears event on fullcalendar.

Please help me to add this changes in fullcalendar. Thanks.

Comment: I found CSS for tweaking event time: `.fc-event-time {   display: none;  }`, now need help to modify axis time format.

Answer (score 1):

FullCalendar doesn't support an end time in the `axisFormat`, but by doing a few minor changes in the FullCalendar source code it becomes possible. I've provided a solution to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547384/198065.

You can hide the time in the events simply by providing setting `timeFormat: ''`.

Comment: I've made my changes in v. 1.6.1 and you can download the edited file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrvr37s6e8f46oa/fullcalendar.js. Notice that you have to set the `axisFormat` in this way `axisFormat: 'H:mm - {H:mm}'`.

Comment: I have downloaded file and upload to my js dir. and made all changes instructed by you but still not working. Check: https://www.dropbox.com/s/keesi2n03960o9i/fc-tweak-fails.jpg , what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar does support an end time in the axisFormat. 
Just try below code to view 10:00 am - 10:45 am , 11:00 am - 11:45 am, etc..

```
axisFormat: 'h:mm tt - h:45 tt',

timeFormat: {
    agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
},
```